Better approach to refactoring a component
I have a component which is an order form. It slightly changes depending on the type of delivery. The order can either be delivered by a company or it can be self-picked by client. And depending on that some headings change, form gets the third tab and etc. Right now what I do is I manipulate this with isCollect variable. I pass it as a prop to all children components thus creating props drilling which I think can be avoided.
I use redux in my project but I also don't think that using isCollect there is a good idea since I'll have to import useSelector and access that variable in every component down the line.
What would be better way to refactor this?
import KeyboardArrowLeftIcon from "@mui/icons-material/KeyboardArrowLeft";
import { Box, Button, Grid, Paper, Toolbar, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import DeliveryOIAdditionalInfo from "../../Components/DeliveryOI/DeliveryOIAdditionalInfo/DeliveryOIAdditionalInfo";
import DeliveryOIConfirmation from "../../Components/DeliveryOI/DeliveryOIConfirmation/DeliveryOIConfirmation";
import DeliveryOIOverview from "../../Components/DeliveryOI/DeliveryOIOverview/DeliveryOIOverview";
import DeliveryOITabsForm from "../../Components/DeliveryOI/DeliveryOITabsForm/DeliveryOITabsForm";
import { PageHeading } from "../../Components/UI/Typography/SharedTypography";
import { useGetDeliveryOptionsQuery } from "../../redux/api/deliveryApiSlice";
import {
  setIsConfirmation,
  setIsTabsFormOpen,
} from "../../redux/slices/deliveryOI/deliveryOI";

const OrderIntake = ({ isCollect = false }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const isConfirmation = useSelector(
    (state) => state.deliveryOI.isConfirmation
  );

  const { isLoading: isLoadingDeliveries, isSuccess: isSuccessDeliveries } =
    useGetDeliveryOptionsQuery(isCollect ? "collect" : "deliver");

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(setIsConfirmation(false));
    dispatch(setIsTabsFormOpen(true));
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <>
      <Toolbar sx={{ backgroundColor: "text.primary" }}>
        <Button
          onClick={() => navigate(-1)}
          sx={{
            color: "white",
            "&:hover": { textDecoration: "underline" },
            "& .MuiButton-startIcon>*:nth-of-type(1)": {
              fontSize: "30px",
              paddingBottom: "2px",
            },
          }}
          startIcon={<KeyboardArrowLeftIcon />}
        >
          <PageHeading>
            {isCollect
              ? "GENERATE PIN CODE FORPICK UP"
              : "SCHEDULE NEW DELIVERY"}
          </PageHeading>
        </Button>
      </Toolbar>
      <Box
        sx={{
          p: { md: 4 },
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
        }}
      >
        {isLoadingDeliveries && (
          <Typography sx={{ color: "white" }}>Loading!</Typography>
        )}
        {isSuccessDeliveries && (
          <Grid container maxWidth="1280px">
            <Grid item xs={12} md={8} sx={{ marginBottom: { xs: 4, md: 0 } }}>
              <Paper square={false} sx={{ padding: 4 }}>
                {isConfirmation ? (
                  <DeliveryOIConfirmation />
                ) : (
                  <DeliveryOIOverview isCollect={isCollect} />
                )}
              </Paper>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} md={4} sx={{ paddingLeft: { xs: "0", md: 2 } }}>
              <Paper square={false} sx={{ p: 4 }}>
                {isConfirmation ? (
                  <DeliveryOIAdditionalInfo />
                ) : (
                  <DeliveryOITabsForm isCollect={isCollect} />
                )}
              </Paper>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        )}
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};

export default OrderIntake;


